# GCP alert to not autoresolve

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

We have created a GCP alert based on the log based metric we created i.e whenever an error comes in the logs (while dataflow runs) if spike comes above threshold alert mail will be triggered . This is working fine

The issue is that they always auto-resolve the incident created as the spike comes down in the next minute as there is no error in the log....

Is there a way on GCP side not to resolve the incident. The Support/developer person should manually close the incident after resolving the error occurred in the dataflow

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. It looks like GCP does not support disabling the auto-close feature once an alert condition has returned to baseline.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Closing incidents documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#closing_incidents):

*"Incidents are closed automatically; you cannot close an incident. An incident is closed when the system observed that the condition is no longer being met or when 7 days have passed without an observation that the condition is still being met."*

Which means that currently it is not possible to set an incident to not auto-resolve, however, there is an open Feature Request in Public Issue Tracker to have this functionality implemented:

[[FR] Add an option to not auto_resolve incidents in AlertPolicy](https://issuetracker.google.com/151052441)

If you “star” the request you will receive notifications for any important updates and keep track of its progress.

Comment: This is different thatn what OP asked, this auto resolve feature says to resolve automatically if it kept open for x days, what OP asked is as soon as it becomes below threshold it resolves the incident